# How do I replace an element in an array with a string from another parameter

Tags: python, arrays, function, replace, parameters

So I am a beginner in Python and programming.

How can I replace an element in an array with a string from another parameter.

Basically lets say there is an `array = ["a","s","d","f","g","h]`

and I want to replace the 3rd element of that array with a string "Z".

This is what I have came up with

```py
def xyz(array,string):
    string = ("")
    array = []

    for value in array:
        replace = value.replace(3,"string")
        return replace
```

Comment: In Python these are called lists, not arrays.

Comment: List/array indexes in almost all programming languages count from 0. So the third element is index 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
array[2]='Z'
```

then this is what you get:

```
array = ["a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h"]
array[2]
>>'d'
array[2]='Z'
array
>>['a', 's', 'Z', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the list directly like this:

```
array[2] = "Z"
```